# ISO file in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Is it possible to create an ISO file of an DVD in C++ using IMAPI2 ?.How ?.Can you give me sample code.I checked in internet for 4 more days.But I couldn't find a sample.Hope that help me.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

I don't know very much about this topic, but a simple google search answered me back this page with even sample code (I spent less than one minute):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/IMAPI2.aspx

You can do **everything** with C++, specially if you are not interested in your source code being portable (in this case, it seems that the IMAPI library is something owned by Microsoft Windows).